# How can I resize and watermark images in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for gems that will allow me to resize and watermark uploaded images.

I see a lot of posts on ImageScience and Mini-Magick but nothing that recent. I am looking for any experiences that will help me make a decision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree/master) to upload the images.

With Paperclip you define how you want the images to be processed after uploading.

Auto resizing is accomplished by setting values in your upload Model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
 end
```

Here is a good example of creating a [Post Processors](http://mdeering.com/posts/018-paperclip-processors-doing-so-much-more-with-your-attachment) and another for adding a [watermark with ImageMagick](http://joakim.erdfelt.com/wiki/index.php/AddingWatermarksWithImageMagick).

Of note is that you already have an application (with uploaded images) live, you can "re-run" the Paperclip commands over it again with the command:

```
rake paperclip:refresh ModelName RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: on mine (v2.4.5), that's rake paperclip:refresh class=ModelName

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) on a couple of products and it is working fine for me.  However, people constantly complain about [its memory usage](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=RMagick+memory+problems&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).  The documentation can be a little confusing though.

A new project that I have heard good things about is [MagickWand for Ruby](http://magickwand.rubyforge.org/).  But I don't have any experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

I just recommend a gem I wrote myself:

Github page: https://github.com/wrymax/image_clipper

It's very simple using it to resize and watermarking image. Also it works well with Paperclip in ROR.

Simply add:

```
gem install image_clipper
```

And install ImageMagick as basic image processing lib:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Sample code:

```
image.resize('200x100', save_new_file_path)

image.resize('35%')

image.watermarking(watermark_image_path)
```

Hope it helps.